# Django ModelForm, having a foreign key as a hidden field

Tags: python, django

I'm basically building a very trivial form. Let's stick to the books/publisher examples given in the django tutorials and build upon that.

I have a user login to the web app, at which point the first thing they can do is click on a publisher. This publisher then gets saved for their session. Upon that I take them to a create book form. In there I embed the the publisher's id from the database into a hidden field.

Upon the user submitting an HTTP POST, I do something like:

```
mybookform = BookForm(request.POST)
if mybookform.is_valid():
    abook = mybookform.save(commit=False)
    abook.publisher_id = request.POST['publisher_id']
    mybookform.save()
```

Yes there's a few naive things done here, such as blindly grabbing the publisher_id and verifying if it's indeed a real publisher id, amongst other security issues. Let's just not pay attention to that for the moment.

My question is, is there a better way of handling this? Although hypothetically this example doesn't make logistical sense, in my particular app the example actually makes sense. The problem is I get a ValueError exception saying publisher_id needs to be a Publisher instance.

Now I can easily retrieve a publisher instance with Publisher.objects.filter(id=..) and use that instead. The question is, is it really necessary? Can I avoid the additional query to the database and somehow update this form instance in a more 'elegant' fashion?

Also, is it possible to somehow embed the publisher in a hidden field so that I do not need to do mybookform.save(commit=False) and just do mybookform = BookForm(request.POST) followed by mybookform.save() immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the instance of the publisher does protect against client-side changes that might reference a completely invalid publisher.

To your second question, yes you can include that field as a hidden field by [overriding the field in the ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types) with the approriate form field setting the `widget` to [HiddenInput](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.HiddenInput).

Comment: Thanks John. Only problem is, your answer doesn't help me figure out how to make sure my hidden input contains the correct instance of the publisher_id.

Comment: There has been some discussion by Simon Willison about signed cookies and, more generally, including general signing in Django core (http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/133509246caf1d91).  You could cryptographically sign a cookie or the value of the hidden field using Simon's sign.py (http://github.com/simonw/django-openid/blob/master/django_openid/signed.py)

Comment: nono. I'm not worried about encrypting cookies. I already have code for that. My problem is, the foreign key references a publisher, but it can only be one publisher. I don't know how to set the hidden publisher field to be that of the instance that the user originally put in when logging in to the app.

Comment: As of Django1.9, It is impossible for me to overide widget for modelchoicefield, to HiddenInput instead of select. I'm also trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way to do this.

I would use the [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) function for this.

And yes, you can prevent this to be modified by the user by setting the model field to [editable=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form),